# How do you add plugins to SBT? [Ubuntu]

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, sbt

I am following the instructions on how to add plugins to Eclipse for SBT here:

https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse

> Add sbteclipse to your plugin definition file (or create one if
>   doesn't exist). You can use either: the global file (for version 0.13
>   and up) at ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt the project-specific file
>   at PROJECT_DIR/project/plugins.sbt

However, the directory does not exist in Ubuntu linux. All I see is ~/.sbt and inside of that a directory called /boot. What should I do? Is the /0.13 directory somewhere else on my computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just create folder next to `boot` under `~/.sbt/` with the full path, as it is asked in the documentation, just do

```
touch ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt
```

to create a global file with plugins.